# ReferenceEquals returning false with strings

Tags: c#

```
    private class global
    {
        public static int a = 0;
        public static int val = 0;
        public static int c = -1;
        public static string g = "";
    }
    private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        global.a = global.a + 1;
        global.c = global.c + 1;
        string a = label2.Text;
        if (string.ReferenceEquals(a, global.g))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("a");
            //dataGridView1.Rows[global.c].Cells[1].Value = global.a;
            //dataGridView1.Rows[global.c].Cells[2].Value = global.val * global.a;
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(label2.Text, global.a, global.val);
        }
        global.g = label2.Text;
    }
```

If `button8` is pressed again with `label2.Text` it should call `MessageBox.Show()` but somehow `global.g = label2.text` does not work. I tried with :

```
    string a = "";
    string b = "";
    if (string.ReferenceEquals(a, b))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("a");
    }
```

It works fine but then I change b to global.g it skips if...

Comment: Why you are trying to use `string.ReferenceEquals` and not `string.Equals` or `==`

Comment: Well, there are more problems here. Reference equality of strings is not generally a good idea (strings are immutable...), you should use String.Equals instead. But for String.Empty it's a special case, as there is only one String.Empty per application domain, so ReferenceEquals for that will return true...

Comment: Becouse I was told that string.ReferenceEquals are best way and it works fine .

Comment: I'm amazed ReferenceEquals works at all in your example.

Comment: @NickUdell string interning... Not just for string.Empty, by the way.

Comment: Well it works with if `(string.ReferenceEquals(a, b)).` How should I change my code?

Comment: Ah yeah, just read @qqbenq's comment. It's pretty cool.

Comment: Nvm guys someguys confused me that strings can only be compared that way. Thank you for your help you solved my probelm.

Comment: @qqbenq you missed "Interning"

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Yeah, sorry, I really did not include it in my comment, but fortunately it is already mentioned in some of the answers, so hopefully everyone will be informed about that :)

Comment: @qqbenq Never mind, your comment nailed it. +1 :)

Comment: Related post - [How ReferenceEquals can understand references belong same object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3396589/465053)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As qqbenq states above... you should use `String.Equals` instead due to string interning.

You should **NOT** use reference equality to compare strings... as per [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183759.aspx)

> you should not use ReferenceEquals to
>   determine string equality.

And a bit more detail further down in the link...

> Constant strings within the same assembly are always interned by the
>   runtime. That is, only one instance of each unique literal string is
>   maintained. However, the runtime does not guarantee that strings
>   created at runtime are interned, nor does it guarantee that two equal
>   constant strings in different assemblies are interned.

Specifically to answer your question...  how should I change my code...

**Edited** as @Servy mentioned to use the static `string.equals` for the case where a is null.

```
    string a = "";
    string b = "";
    if (string.Equals(a, b))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("a");
    }
```

You should pretty much always use `Equals` for comparing reference types.  Only use `ReferenceEquals` if you really want to check if they are not only equal but actually point to the same reference.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is the use of [ReferenceEquals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of [Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.equals%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

ReferenceEquals will check for equality of the *reference* - which is to say, the pointer in memory to the underlying variable, not the value itself. this is a static method because it has such a precise use, it should never be overridden or hidden by a derived class.

Equals on the other hand will compare the objects themselves, and thus determine if their underlying values are the same. Since it's a string, you also have overloads of [Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.equals%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which allow to specify exactly how the strings are being compared.

thus, change

```
if (string.ReferenceEquals(a, global.g))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("a");
        //dataGridView1.Rows[global.c].Cells[1].Value = global.a;
        //dataGridView1.Rows[global.c].Cells[2].Value = global.val * global.a;
    }
```

to

```
if (string.Equals(a, global.g))    // Static string.Equals prevents a NullReferenceException if 'a' is null
    {
        MessageBox.Show("a");
        //dataGridView1.Rows[global.c].Cells[1].Value = global.a;
        //dataGridView1.Rows[global.c].Cells[2].Value = global.val * global.a;
    }
```

Generally, you want to use [Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.equals%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for comparison. [ReferenceEquals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has some very very specific use cases, and I've only ever had to use it once.

Comment: You should be using the static `string.Equals` method, not the instance method, for proper handling of null values.

Comment: @Servy Right you are there, assuming you want nulls to pass. Will update my answer accordingly

Comment: Null values don't automatically pass.  Null is equal to null, and not equal to anything else, according to `string.Equals`, which is sensible.  Another possibility is to return `null` instead of `true` or `false`, but they didn't go that route.  Throwing an exception usually *isn't* the desirable behavior in this type of situation.

Comment: @Servy by "pass" I meant "not stop becasue of an exception." ;)