# View address location of a variable in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Is there any option in the Visual Studio watch window to show variable address locations like 0x00? I am asking this because I would like to better understand how thing work in the lower level.

Answer (score 2):

You're best option is probably to load the [SOS extension into VS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6d2sxs.aspx). This will allow you to inspect the heap and the actual memory used by the instances.

Please take a look at [my answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355801/displaying-the-value-of-a-reference-to-an-object/3355972#3355972) as it has related info.